# Is $\log (t^2 (l/c)) = \log (t^2) \log (l/c)$?

Tags: logarithms

I'm new in this forum want to ask a beginner question about logarithm:

> Is $\log (t^2 (l/c)) = \log (t^2)  \log (l/c)$?

Comment: No, this is not right.

Comment: thanks how can i make it right ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Comment: If you're learning logarithms, you should have been introduced to the product rule, quotient rule, and power rule.  Note that in the log argument you have a product...what can you say about that?

Comment: In general this is what you have: $\log(ab) = \log(a)+\log(b)$. Instead of multiplication, you need addition up there.

Comment: @CameronWilliams many thanks i didn't use logarithm for a long time so i know that it's beginner question i searched but i though i searhed with wrong way , Thanks agian

Comment: @user5520049 No problem :) That's what we're here for.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main rules:

1)  Product rule:

$$\log_b{xy}=\log_b{x}+\log_b{y}$$

2)  Power rule: (can be derived from (1))

$$\log_b{x^n}=n\cdot \log_b{x}$$

2)  Quotient rule: (can be derived from (1) and (2))

$$\log_b{\frac{x}{y}}=\log_b{x}-\log_b{y}$$

Now note that the expression in your argument is

$$t^2\cdot\frac{l}{c}$$

which involves all three rule cases.  See if you can work slowly rule by rule and unravel the expression.